# HTML compresson in zend

Tags: optimization, zend-framework

I am new to zend. I am using gzip compression for my website. For this I have done the setting in php.ini for this. It is working fine.

Now the issue is, before compressing the html or better to say the response I want to remove all the blank spaces and new lines from the html, so that it will be compressed and then I will apply the gzip compression.

Now my question is - that when i am using the following plugin :

```
class My_Plugin_Plugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

  public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
  {
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $body = $response->getBody();
$body = preg_replace('|\s+|', '', $body);
    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    $response->setBody($body);
  }
}
```

,I get only the page view content, but it did not show the content of layout. How can i get the whole content of the page including layout content

Answer (score 3):

You can use a controller plugin and hook up the `postDispatch` method and manipulate the response from there.

```
class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $body = $response->getBody();
        $body = preg_replace('|\s+|', '', $body);
        $response->setBody($body);
    }


}
```

Somewhere in your bootstrap:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setControllerDirectory('/path/to/controllers')
      ->setRouter(new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite())
      ->registerPlugin(new MyPlugin());
$front->dispatch();
```

Note: since the space would get compressed anyway I don't think it's really worth the trouble